# Implementing comments and notifications using Facebook plugins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have a reviews website where I want to integrate Facebook social plugins. I initially thought of integrating facebook comment plugin where users can write their reviews for the products I have listed on my site. But that seemed like laying waste to my own review functionality.

Here's the flow I came up with:

- create a facebook app for the website
- Users write a review and post it to their facebook profile
- When some action happens on the review like when it is voted up or replied to, the user who posted the review to facebook gets notified via the facebook notification center
- I fetch the likes, replies on facebook post and display them on my website on the review

Is it possible to implement this workflow? I basically want to send notifications to user from  inside my website not from the facebook application I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using [apprequests](http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/apprequests). One requirement for this to work is your website and facebook canvas app must be registered under the same 'app' (ie have the same appID) and be under the same base domain.